# Instância no model do Django com problema

Tags: python, django, instanciar-objeto

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com vários apps. O model do app de departamentos é o seguinte:

```
from emails.models import GerenciarEmails

class Departamento(models.Model):
#modelo de grupos de disciplinas
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Departamento'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Departamentos'
titulo = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Nome do Grupo')
watermark = models.FileField(upload_to = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"/watermarks/", default=settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/img/generico.gif')
cor = ColorField(blank=True)
gerencia = models.ForeignKey(GerenciarEmails)
docentes_responsaveis = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True,related_name="docentes_responsaveis_pelo_grupo", limit_choices_to={'docente':True})
def __unicode__(self):
    #Modo como o Modelo e Exibido na Lista na Adminstracao
    return unicode(self.titulo)
```

Eu adicionei a seguinte instância nele:

```
gerencia = models.ForeignKey(GerenciarEmails)
```

GerenciarEmails é um método do model do app de emails. O *import* que interessa é esse usado, os outros são referentes a outras coisas.

Com a inserção dessa instância, o Django dá o seguinte erro: **ImportError: cannot import name Departamento**

Aparentemente ele não está deixando inserir essa instância. Alguém poderia  me ajudar sobre o motivo do erro?

Este é o método **GerenciarEmails**:

```
class GerenciarEmails(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Gerenciar E-mails'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Gerenciar E-mails'
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.departamento.titulo
```

Como dá para ver, eu uso o método Departamento, do models.py do app Departamentos. Se eu colocar o import depois desse método, como é a sugestão do **mgibsonbr**, o python dá outro erro:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Disciplina
```

Até que faz sentido, pois **GerenciarEmails** precisa do import de **Departamento**.

Comment: Coloque o traceback completo do erro, vai ajudar a resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Como na pergunta de outro usuario do Stack, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845366/importerror-cannot-import-name Acredito que irá te ajudar.

Comment: Se sua app A depende (importa) de B, e B por sua vez depende de A, há algum problema na sua modelagem. Provavelmente ambos os modelos (`Departamento` e `GerenciarEmails`) deveriam fazer parte da mesma app, e você deve criar os modelos na ordem certa (dependido antes de dependente).

Comment: Acho que percebi seu problema. Você tem a tabela Departamento com uma FK para GerenciarEmails, e GerenciarEmails com uma FK para departamento?! Isso não pode, nem no Django nem em qualquer banco de dados relacional. Só uma pode ter FK pra outra. Se a relação for de 1 para 1, escolha um dos modelos (sugiro GerenciarEmails) e coloque um OneToOneField nele, e só. O outro modelo terá automaticamente um campo para a relação inversa. Mas no BD a chave estrangeira tem de estar numa tabela só.

Answer (score 3):

Primeira coisa é verificar a estrutura de pastas do seu projeto, talvez você tenha que colocar

```
from seuprojeto.emails.models import GerenciarEmails
```

Caso não seja isto, provavelmente é o problema que o mgibsonbr disse nos comentários: "Se sua app A depende (importa) de B, e B por sua vez depende de A".
Utilize a ForeignKey dessa maneira para matar o problema:

```
gerencia = models.ForeignKey('emails.GerenciarEmails')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, porém elas não resolveram o problema. Eu estou achando que deve ser mais complicado mesmo, conforme o que os demais responderam. Eu vou fazer a sugestão do mgibsonbr, e se precisar, me aprofundar melhor sobre dependência circular.

Comment: Como eu disse @BrunoDerissoSalvini isso pode estar relacionado a  estrutura.
Se você olhar a documentação do django, ele sugere pra fazer como eu disse. E nunca tive problemas dessa maneira.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey
Mas você deve avaliar a sua modelagem também porque ela pode não estar boa.

Answer (score 2):

Sua mensagem de erro é um indício de **dependência circular**. Por acaso você não teria, em `emails/models.py`, uma linha fazendo:

```
from departamentos.models import Departamento
```

? Esse código funcionava antes, porque a app `emails` dependia de `departamentos`, então quando `emails/models.py` era carregado, ela fazia o *import*, carregava a app `departamentos` **inteira**, e então prosseguia para ler o conteúdo da app `emails`.

Quando você fez com que `departamentos` passasse *também* a depender de `emails` (a propósito, o que está provocando o erro é o `import`, não a criação do campo), então temos um problema:

- O Python começa a ler `departamentos/models.py`; cria o módulo, vazio;
- Ele lê a linha que pede pra importar `emails.models`; o módulo ainda não foi lido;
- Ele começa a ler `emails/models.py`; cria o módulo, vazio;
- Ele lê a linha que pede pra importar `departamentos.models`; o módulo existe, mas está vazio;
- Ele tenta ler `Departamento` no módulo importado; esse nome não existe, pois o módulo está vazio;
- `ImportError: cannot import name Departamento`

Solucionar isso não é fácil, e pode envolver refatorar seu código (mudar modelos de app). Se você tivesse *certeza* que a app `emails` fosse ser carregada antes da app `departamentos`, você poderia colocar o `import` não no início do arquivo, mas sim depois da criação do modelo `GerenciarEmails`:

emails/models.py

```
... # Nada que faça uso de Departamento

class GerenciarEmails(models.Model):
    ...

from departamentos.models import Departamento

... # Coisas que dependem de Departamento
```

Assim, a app `emails` seria lida até o ponto em que define `GerenciarEmails`, com o import a app `departamentos` seria lida inteira (e ela teria acesso a `GerenciarEmails`, já que o mesmo já foi incluído no módulo) e então o `emails/models.py` continuaria sua leitura normalmente. Funciona, o difícil é garantir essa ordem de leitura (se o `departamentos` fosse lido primeiro, acabou, não tem jeito de "consertar" a ordem).

Na [resposta do Puam Dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97992/215) ele sugere especificar a chave estrangeira usando uma string, em vez de uma referência direta pra um modelo:

```
gerencia = models.ForeignKey('emails.GerenciarEmails')
```

Se você fizer isso, **sem importar a app `emails`**, pode funcionar (não sei dizer, pois nunca usei essa construção). Se nada mais der certo, então só resta mover seus modelos de uma app pra outra até que não existam mais dependências circulares entre apps.

Comment: Funciona sim, e é até uma boa prática, mas também é necessário ele ver a modelagem dele conforme você indicou. Talvez isto não esteja legal.

Comment: @PuamDias Quando falei em "funcionar" quis dizer que não sabia se, na presença de uma dependência circular, isso ia ou não "quebrar a dependência". Precisaria testar pra ter certeza.

Comment: Sem importar a app emails não funciona, o python dá outro erro: `departamentos.departamento: Reverse query name for field 'gerencia' clashes with field 'GerenciarEmails.departamento'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'gerencia'.`

Comment: Estou vendo sobre a sua sugestão, e se não der certo também, irei me aprofundar melhor sobre essa **dependência circular**, mas já deu pra entender o que ela é.

Comment: @BrunoDerissoSalvini Esse erro pode ser resolvido, colocando um [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) no campo, como sugerido. Você sabe como ele funciona? Se não souber, faça uma pergunta separada e eu explico melhor (muito longo pra fazer nesse cometário rsrs).